# Imdb description

Tags: android, imdb

In my app I have list of movies, that updates dynamically.
Is it possible when user click on movie item, to start installed Imdb app and to show movie description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use

```
imdb:///name/<nameID>
imdb:///find?q=<search_query>
imdb:///title/<titleID>
```

as an URI parameter in your intent. For example

```
startActivity(android.intent.action.VIEW, imdb:///title/<titleID>);
```

For more information see http://www.openintents.org/en/uris and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Great, this works. Is there a way to get TitleId somehow from movie name? because that's all I have.

Comment: That was the first question I asked myself, too. I don't know how much effort it will be, but I'm afraid that you have to add the titleID to your database (or where your movie list comes from) by hand. I don't think that there is a reliable method to get the ID from a specific title. I found a php scraping script for imdb but I never used it on my own and I'm not familiar with scraping but maybe it helps: [scraping skript](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb/imdb.txt)

Comment: Tnx for answer, I will see what I can do with it. I found earlier some IMDB API, but it's not official and I don't want to use it, couse it can be easily changed without warning :)

Comment: what is that? you need to create intent instance `Intent(android.intent.action.VIEW, Uri.parse("URL"))` , such a weird answer, p.s. this doesn't work for the latest IMDb version or Android