# Android open external IMDB application from my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imdb

I have a button in my application which opens the imdb application in the phone with a imdb id I received from https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction

But I couldnt find anyway(using intents) to make my app recognize the imdb app and open it and if imdb app do not exist then I want to open the web site. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If the IMDB app registers an intent filter for its URLs, then just viewing the URL should open the app.  If it doesn't, then you can get the list of installed apps and look for the imdb one by name, and either create an intent for it, or create an intent for the http URL.

Comment: just open the IMDB url with the ID as if you wanted to open a page on IMDB site. If user has IMDB app installed, he will be offered to choose whether he wants to open your link with IMDB app or a browser.

Comment: These two were the answers I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may be able to point you in the right direction. Just to be sure, you seem to be using TMDB but wish to open in the IMDB app?

The code below is from [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters).

It will start your intent if the package manager can find an app with the appropriate intent filter installed on your device. If multiple apps are able to open this intent then an app chooser should pop up, unless the user has previously set a default for this kind of URI.

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  // Always use string resources for UI text.
  // This says something like "Share this photo with"
  String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
  // Create intent to show the chooser dialog
  Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);

  // Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
  if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivity(chooser);
  }
```

If you add an else onto that then you can use a view intent like this :

```
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieUrl));
//Watch out here , There is a URI and Uri class!!!!
if (internetIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(internetIntent);
}
```

I also found this (rather old) post about calling an explicit imdb uri
[Imdb description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135379/imdb-description)

```
startActivity(android.intent.action.VIEW, imdb:///title/<titleID>);
// take note of the Uri scheme "imdb"
```

I hope this helps. If you post some more detail , code, links , I might be able to work through this with you.

If my answer is way off base then please be kind and set me right. We are all learning every day!
Good Luck.